# java jackson deserialization with different type of nested objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have json field s like below. How can I deserialize it to String,String Map?

```
s:{
    "g":0.0,
    "p":0.0,
    "m":0.0,
    "media":{
        "1":{"key":0,"value":0},
        "2":{"key":0,"value":0},
        "3":{"key":0,"value":0},
        "4":{"key":0,"value":0},
        ...},
    "pr":{
        "1":{"key":0,"value":0},
        "2":{"key":0,"value":0},
        "3":{"key":0,"value":0},
    ...}
    }
```

I have tried like that

```
        public JsonNode s;
        @JsonGetter("s")
        public Map<String,String> getS() {
            if (s == null) {
                return null;
            }
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Object> map;
            map = mapper.convertValue(score, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
            Map<String,String> result;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue() instanceof String){
                    result.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

and it's work for test, however I receive next error for real data

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT
>   token  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference
>   chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["media"])

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

According to the model

```
@JsonGetter("s")
public Map<String,String> getS()
```

`s` is a `Map<String,String>` but the `media` in JSON seems to be an `Object` instead (probably a `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`)

```
"media":{
    "1":{"key":0,"value":0},
    "2":{"key":0,"value":0},
    "3":{"key":0,"value":0},
    "4":{"key":0,"value":0},
 ...},
```

Probably you should use

```
@JsonGetter("s")
public Map<String,Object> getS()
```

and then cast the Object further .

Comment: What's the difference with my attempt?I have firstly converted to map<String,Object> and then to map<String,String>. How should I cast it in your proposal?

Comment: @Sergei `s` is not a `Map<String, String>` furthermore there are 3 level of nesting to get the key value within `media`

Comment: Solved like this for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
              
            }

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it like below

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {      
         result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
      }
```